# How to write a good hashCode() for permutations?

Tags: java, hash, permutation, hashcode

In my program, I handle a lot of lists of size *n* that all are permutations of [1,...,*n*]. My problem is that I put these permutations in `HashMap`s and `HashSet`s, and I need a good `hashCode()` that avoids too many collisions.

All the solutions I have thought of lead to either a lot of collisions or an overflow.
How can I write a good hashCode for permutations ?

Comment: If your lists have more than 12 items, then collisions are inevitable, because there are more then 2**32 permutations of them. Or do your permutations have any particular properties which mean that there are fewer?

Comment: Actually it is very likely that there will be more than 12 items. But the first approach I tried had collisions with only four items.

Comment: @Romain: There's absolutely no reason to prevent overflow, no sane hashing algorithm does it. Note that at the end, some more bits of the hash get dropped in order to obtain the index in the underlying array. A good hash function is e.g. `com.google.common.hash.Hashing.murmur3_32` from Guava.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried a '[rotating hash](http://burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/examhash.html)'? You could adjust the barrel rotate amount to see if it makes much difference to the hash distribution.

Answer (score 4):

Please see link in karmakaze's answer. It shows a rotating shift in much neater code, and discusses the general details (and issues) with different basic hashes.

---

An overflow isn't bad. Just modulus it back in :-) Consider just a simple shift with an XOR and feed the "overflow" back into the stream?

Consider, for each element, with value i, where h is a long:

```
h ^= i;          // XOR in new data
h <<= 11;        // shift with a relatively long cycle
h ^= (h >>> 32); // feed the "overflow" back into the input
h &= 0xFFFF;     // throw out "overflow"
```

Happy coding.

Comment: Throwing away bits is never a good idea, no sane hash does it.

Answer (score 2):

you can take the first n primes and do

```
int hash = 0;
for(int i = 0; i<n;i++){
    hash +=  perm[i]*prime[i];//really unique will be hash +=Math.pow(prime[i],perm[i]) but will be to computationally heavy
}
```

the overflow is a pretty good thing as you'll then be sure to have all bits engaged in the hash